# Flutter - Do not restart application when restoring

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, dart, backgroundworker

Friends,

does anyone know how to prevent the application from restarting when restoring it? For example, the application is minimized, then restored and it restarts, any way to avoid it?

Comment: Please share your code. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is platform dependent, per example in android it depends on the ram available, if the device needs to free resources it will [kill your app](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle) , if you add some native code to handle this you could do some things to [prevent android from doing this](https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/keep-flutter-running-background-on-android-6ffc85be0234). However. It's NOT recommended to do this. If the user exits an app, it wants that, to close the app. If the user presses the home button, it wants to go to another app, and android will keep your app running for some time in case your user comes back to the app.

The best way to do this, is to handle the [default flutter lifecycle](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7) to store important data in case the system kills the app.